# Too Much Spam :(

Tags: support, spam

Recently in GDSE the spam increased a **lot**; there is company or person who is spamming about keto diet all the time; I flagged and downvoted a lot but isn't there any other way to stop this?

Comment: Posting a screenshot of the spam here is not really a good thing, since now the spammer has something to show to their employer (and somebody might actually buy that stuff). I will remove the link and have the questions history redacted. You do not need to do anything (except avoiding to repeat that mistake).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft sorry will keep that in mind :) thanks for the reply

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3115/19174

Comment: Are there companies? Yes, most likely. Based on the long-term effort, someone is definitely paid for it. GDSE isn't the only site affected  though: the entire network is to some degree. Keep flagging though, and Spam Ram (SE's built in spam filter) will eventually start blocking some of it, along with IPs. SmokeDetector (spam detection bot, not affiliated with SE) will also pick up most of it and result in auto-flags to get it off the site quicker. Beyond that, there's not really much to do about it.

Comment: @Zoe i'm already happy with the results cuz even in less than 3 minutes or so it's being deleted already ^^

Comment: You can read about autoflagging [here](https://charcoal-se.org/flagging), feel free to pop into [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540) chat room with any questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for your concern Design Phoenix. Spam can be very annoying and potentially hurtful to the site and the community.

Luckily, we have some automated tools at our disposal to deal with spam. These tools look for bad keywords, bad urls, blacklisted sites, etc. *Keto* and *Diet* are definitely among those keywords.

We actually have a chat room where this automated system posts everything that is automatically flagged as spam: [The Spam Blot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/56223). As you can see, it's quite a lot, more than any one person could deal with.

If you want a more in-depth analysis of the automated anti-spam activity, you can find a dashboard [here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/sites/dash?utf8=%E2%9C%93&site_id=68&months=3&tab=all). It looks as though the amount of spam has not really increased over the past three months.

[image]

One thing to note though is that the time to deletion has increased somewhat during the past weeks. This might be due a lessened user activity overall (maybe because of the Easter Holidays?). This might explain why the users that *are* still active, are seeing more of the spam.

[image]

This is definitely something we do need to keep an eye on. I'm guessing the Time to deletion will go down by itself again once user activity picks up. But if it doesn't, we'll maybe have to look into taking additional steps.

---

PS: There's no need to downvote spam. Flagging automatically does this. And once an answer is deleted, the change in rep is removed with it.

Comment: See [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49983882#49983882) for the reason of the recent increase in deletion times.

Comment: Thanks @Wrzlprmft. So the deletion times should go down automatically if SE stops blocking those IP's...

Comment: It's good to see that we have already anti spam system here :) marked as solved

Comment: I think you meant *the time to deletion has **increased***

Comment: yes, edited. Thanks for the heads-up @iBugDesign

Comment: Could I suggest replacing The Spam Blot's link with [the transcript link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/56223)? This means those that don't wish to do so aren't automatically joining the room.

Comment: @doppelgreener good idea, I went ahead and did it.

Comment: What if i want to post a design question for a keto diet flyer ;)